# Rails 4 - Running staging on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to run staging environment locally using `rails s -e staging` and `rails c -e staging`.

When the application (or me via console) try to access DB, I get the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: xxx
```

I guess I simply need to create a staging database on my machine, but cannot figure out how.

Comment: You can run staging or production locally using the same database if you want - just edit your `config/database.yml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need a staging section in your database config file, like this:

```
# config/database.yml
# ...
staging:
  adapter: mysql
  database: app_staging
  # ...
```

Be sure you have the file:

```
# environments/staging.rb
```

And create database like this

> $ RAILS_ENV=staging bin/rake db:create

Run migration:

> $ RAILS_ENV=staging bin/rake db:migrate

Answer (score 4):

`rake db:create RAILS_ENV=staging` should work

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake

Comment: Thanks! Actually I got `db/staging.sqlite3 already exists`, so I simply did `rake db:reset RAILS_ENV=staging` and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add the database:

```
# config/database.yml
staging:
  # ...
```

Then generate an usable database:

```
env RAILS_ENV=staging bin/rake db:reset
```

Then run your server / console / etc.:

```
env RAILS_ENV=staging
```

As a tip, `dotenv` accepts `.env.staging`, `.env.test`, `.env.development`, etc. https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv#what-other-env-files-can-i-use